# Python alternatives to nested loops in data frame processing

Tags: python, sql-server

I am new to Python and currently creating a MatchResults (to check if the data is grouped as per defined match rules as part of MDM) based on the data available from SQL Server table. I am connecting to database using Pyodbc and creating a data frame.

Table looks like below MDM_TABLE

[image]

Match Rules :

**Rule 1**: Exact Match of Name and Gender
**Rule 2**: Levenshtein ditance between 2 names should be greater than 75 and exact match on both Gender and Email

I am trying to create a result output some like this and insert results data back into a new table in the database

MDM_TABLE_RESULTS

[image]

I am setting default match type to match for each row in the data frame, first checking for overmatches(multiple rows in the same group id and data is not satisfying at least one rule but present in same group ids) and then checking for Undermatches (data satisfying at least one match rule but present in multiple groups) and then Match(satisfying at least one rule and present in the same group or isolated records which don't have any similar records).

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=[column[0] for column in cursor.description])


def match_rules(row1, row2):

    rule1 = row1['name'] == row2['name'] and row1['gender'] == row2['gender'] 


    name_similarity = ratio(row1['name'], row2['name']) * 100

    rule2 = name_similarity >= 75 and row1['gender'] == row2['gender'] and row1['email'] == 
    row2['email'] 

df['MatchType'] = 'Match'  # Default MatchType
df['Comments'] = ''
start_time = time.time()
total_records = len(df)

for idx, cluster_id in enumerate(df['cluster_id'].unique(), start=1):
    cluster_data = df[df['cluster_id'] == cluster_id]
    if len(cluster_data) > 1:  # Check if there are multiple rows in the cluster
        overmatch_flag = False
        for i in range(len(cluster_data)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(cluster_data)):
                if not match_rules(cluster_data.iloc[i], cluster_data.iloc[j]):
                    overmatch_flag = True
                    mismatched_columns = [col for col in ['name', 'gender', 'email'] if cluster_data.iloc[i][col] != cluster_data.iloc[j][col]]
                    df.loc[cluster_data.index, 'Comments'] += f'Mismatch on columns {mismatched_columns}. '
            if overmatch_flag:
                df.loc[cluster_data.index, 'MatchType'] = 'Overmatch'


for idx, record_id in enumerate(df[df.MatchType != "Overmatch"]['RecordId'].unique(), start=1):
    record_data = df[df.RecordId == record_id]
    undermatch_clusters = []
    for i in range(len(record_data)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
            if df.iloc[j]['RecordId'] != record_id and match_rules(record_data.iloc[i], df.iloc[j]):
                undermatch_clusters.append(df.iloc[j]['cluster_id'])
                df.loc[record_data.iloc[i].name, 'MatchType'] = 'Undermatch'
    if undermatch_clusters:
        unique_clusters = list(set(undermatch_clusters))
        df.loc[record_data.index, 'Comments'] = f'Matching data under different Cluster IDs: {unique_clusters}.'


records = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
cursor.fast_executemany = True
query = "INSERT INTO dbo.MDM_TABLE_RESULTS VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
cursor.executemany(query, records)
conn.commit()

print(f"Inserted a total of {len(records)} records.")
print("Total Execution time of script is --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The above code block is working as expected for the samples, but when I am trying to test for a minimum of 10000 rows, it is executing for hours

Any inputs to improve the performance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.